# How can I serve the collection to cursor parameter?

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql, cursor

Please find rc1 in the code. I want to return `v_TeminatKayit` collection to this cursor. How can I do it?

This does not work;

```
 OPEN RC1 FOR
 SELECT *
   FROM TABLE(CAST(v_TeminatKayit AS t_TeminatTip));
```

this does not working? How can I return collection as cursor as out parameter!?3

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE KRD_SEL_GNAKDIRISKDETAY_SP
    (
       p_MusteriNo IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
       RC1         IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
       RC2         IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    ) AS
       v_RCRTeminat       SYS_REFCURSOR;
       v_UrunAdi          VARCHAR2(80);
       v_RiskTutar        NUMBER(26, 2);
       v_GNakdiRiskToplam NUMBER(26, 2) := 0;
       v_KullandirimTarih DATE;
       v_Vade             DATE;
       v_Muhatap          VARCHAR2(300);
       v_Konu             VARCHAR2(600);
       TYPE t_TeminatTip IS RECORD(
          v_urunAdi   VARCHAR2(80),
          v_mektupTtr NUMBER(26, 2),
          v_mektupTar DATE,
          v_kkrVade   DATE,
          v_muhatap   VARCHAR2(300),
          v_konu      VARCHAR2(600));

       TYPE t_TeminatBilgi IS TABLE OF t_TeminatTip INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
       v_TeminatKayit t_TeminatBilgi;

    BEGIN
       BEGIN
          KRD_SEL_TEMINATMEKTUPRISK_SP(p_MusteriNo => p_MusteriNo, RC1 => v_RCRTeminat);
          IF v_RCRTeminat%ISOPEN THEN
             FETCH v_RCRTeminat BULK COLLECT
                INTO v_TeminatKayit;

          END IF;
       -- how can I serve the collection to cursor parameter ?
          OPEN RC1 FOR
             SELECT *
               FROM TABLE(CAST(v_TeminatKayit AS t_TeminatTip));


       EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
             raise_application_error(-20101, '');
       END;

    END KRD_SEL_GNAKDIRISKDETAY_SP;
```

Comment: Why I want it :  I understand all the answer. I want to make it as in the code of the question because I want to modify some of it contents and then pass it to the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to fetch an unknown quantity of data into memory so you can work with it, which is not common programming practice in PL/SQL.  In a small database this might be fine - but let's imagine for a moment that your database is a BIG database, and you're working with BIG data, and you open a query which returns 100 million rows without realizing how large the return set will be, and you then try to BULK COLLECT this into an in-memory collection. If you're lucky all this will do is cause your process to crash. If you're less lucky you might cause the database instance to go down, which will probably make a DBA somewhere very, very unhappy. And if you're *really* having a bad day you could bring down the server which, while it may be amusing to watch from afar, is usually not much fun when you're close to the action - especially when three DBA's, two sysadmins, and a manager with a red face suddenly appear in your cubicle shouting, "WHAT DID YOU DO?!?!?!?". Really, this is not fun. Don't ask me how I know... :-}

If you want to return a cursor from this routine, your best bet is to rewrite your routine to do exactly that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE KRD_SEL_GNAKDIRISKDETAY_SP
  (
  p_MusteriNo IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
  RC1         IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  RC2         IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    KRD_SEL_TEMINATMEKTUPRISK_SP(p_MusteriNo => p_MusteriNo, RC1 => RC1);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      raise_application_error(-20101, '');
  END;
END KRD_SEL_GNAKDIRISKDETAY_SP;
```

It appears that `KRD_SEL_TEMINATMEKTUPRISK_SP` is kind enough to open your cursor for you - so you're done. The caller of `KRD_SEL_GNAKDIRISKDETAY_SP` should then read from the cursor (which they were going to do anyways, right?) in whatever manner is appropriate.

Best of luck.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I understand all the answer. I want to make it as in the code of the question because I want to modify some of it contents and then pass it to the cursor.